# Exercise related to Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be analytic on $G= \{z:\Re(z)>0\}$,one one,with $\Re  f(z)>0$ for all $z$ in $G$,and $f(a)=a$ for some real number a.Show that $|f'(a)|\leq 1$.

This is the exercise related to Riemann Mapping Theorem. I feel somehow we have to use unique-ness of Riemann map.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to construct new function as $g(z)=f(z)-z$ and $h(z)= exp(f(z)-a)$.But I am not getting anything interesting.

Comment: Don't have time to think through this too much, but I would try taking a conformal transformation that takes the right half plane to the open unit disk and carries $a$ to $0$ (so we have a mapping $\hat f \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ ) and then try to apply the Schwarz Lemma. Note this is extremely related to the other question you asked today.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Brevan Ellefsen, you can proceed this way:

The map $\varphi \colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 0 \right\rbrace$ given by $$\varphi(z) = a \frac{1 -z}{1 +z}$$ is a biholomorphism that satisfies $\varphi(0) = a$. Its inverse $\varphi^{-1} \colon \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 0 \right\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is given by $$\varphi^{-1}(w) = \frac{a -w}{a +w} \, \text{.}$$ Now consider $g = \varphi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi \colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. It satisfies $g(0) = 0$ and $g^{\prime}(0) = f^{\prime}(a)$. Thus, by Schwarz lemma, we have $\left\lvert f^{\prime}(a) \right\rvert \leq 1$.

**Edit:** Note that it was not necessary to write the map $\varphi$ explicitly. Alternatively, we could just have said that, by the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a biholomorphism $\varphi \colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \left\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 0 \right\rbrace$ that satisfies $\varphi(0) = a$ and continue the same way.